# TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'datetime.timedelta'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, lambda

I have a dataframe as below

```
+----------+-----------+
|START_DATE|FINISH_DATE|
+----------+-----------+
|2017-01-02| 2022-09-18|
|2022-09-19| 2025-03-04|
|2025-03-05| 2027-09-14|
|2027-09-15| 2028-12-06|
|2028-12-07| 2031-08-28|
+----------+-----------+
```

The requirement is to compare the start_date and finish_date of consecutive rows.The start_date of the next row should be just 1 more than  the finish_date of previous row.If start_date of every next row is just 1 more than the finish_date of its previous row for all the rows in dataframe ,then it should return True.(This function should return true on dataframe level and not on row level)

I have used  lag window analytical function for this.

```
dfu = df.withColumn('user', lit('user'))  //df is the above dataframe
windowPartition = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("START_DATE")

df_lag =dfu.withColumn('prev_row_startdate',F.lag(dfu['START_DATE'],-1).over(windowPartition))
df_lag_drp=df_lag.na.drop()
```

Below is the output of this

```
+----------+-----------+----+------------------+
|START_DATE|FINISH_DATE|user|prev_row_startdate|
+----------+-----------+----+------------------+
|2017-01-02| 2022-09-18|user|        2022-09-19|
|2022-09-19| 2025-03-04|user|        2025-03-05|
|2025-03-05| 2027-09-14|user|        2027-09-15|
|2027-09-15| 2028-12-06|user|        2028-12-07|
+----------+-----------+----+------------------+
```

I have written a lambda function which calculates the diff but getting the below error

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'datetime.timedelta'>

```
df_dif=df_lag_drp.rdd.map(lambda x: (x["prev_row_startdate"]-x["FINISH_DATE"]))
```

I understand that i need a lambda function which can iterate over each row of "df_lag_drp" dataframe  and should be able to find the difference between "prev_row_startdate" and "start_date" and if the diff is just 1 for every row then it should return true else false  but i am literally stuck on this.
Please let me know if there is any other way of achieving this efficiently.I am using Python3.9 and spark3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use built-in SQL functions whenever possible. `datediff`does exactly what you want: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#datediff.

Then you can aggregate the result (using `.agg(F.max(F.col('delta_date')))`) and check it equals one for every `user` group